# How to handle date variable in machine learning data pre-processing

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, feature-selection

I have a data-set that contains among other variables the time-stamp of the transaction in the format 26-09-2017 15:29:32. I need to find possible correlations and predictions of the sales (lets say in logistic regression). My questions are:

1. How to handle the date format? Shall I convert it to one number (like excel does automatically)? Shall I split it in more variables like day, month, year, hour, mins, seconds? any other possible suggestions?
2. What if I would like to add distinct week number per year? shall I add variable like 342017(week 34 of year 2017)?
3. Shall I make the same for question 2 for quarter of year?

> ```
> #         Datetime               Gender        Purchase
> 1    23/09/2015 00:00:00           0             1
> 2    23/09/2015 01:00:00           1             0
> 3    25/09/2015 02:00:00           1             0
> 4    27/09/2015 03:00:00           1             1
> 5    28/09/2015 04:00:00           0             0
> ```

Comment: This question is very broad. 1) pick a language (R or Python) second. 2) Asking us how/the best way to process your data is not what this site is for, this invites too much opinion. 3) Asking for a book, tool, reference is off-topic for the site as well. Please have a look at this post on what is appropriate for SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Question is very specific for the machine learning issue and I am asking on how people treat this kind of problem. The reason about tagging R and Python is because there are maybe packages that will help overpass the obstacle of data transformation

Comment: I understand your question, and its importance in modeling. But this is not a programming question, i.e. you have no code, errors, incorrect/unexpected/inconsistent results/outputs. You do not even talk about what kind of algorithm you are training with your expected outputs/goals. If you want to discuss the pros/cons of various representations of date for machine learning/modeling I would suggest [Datascience Stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Actually I do. I am talking about logistic regression. Indeed my 4th question is off topic though and I thank you for that. Do you have anything to contribute with the rest of my question though? e.g. would it be better if I could use the number 42270 instead of 23/09/2015 00:00:00 ? Shall I add another  variable to show e.g. day name?

Comment: First, R and python show dates in human readable format but represent them internally as secs or min or days from an origin time (e.g. 1970-01-01). You can represent your date column as day of the week, quarter (1:4), week (1:52), time from major holiday, time from last full moon, day of the month, day of the year (1:365) time between sales,  season, time from start of sale or promotion, etc., etc. etc. The real question is how do you want to interpret your model variables? Lastly, R and python have packages to make working with dates very easy.

Comment: check the library Feature-engine: https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_doc/datetime/DatetimeFeatures.html and https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_doc/creation/CyclicalFeatures.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Some random thoughts:

Dates are good sources for feature engineering, I don't think there is one method to use dates in a model. Business user expertise would be great; are there observed trends that can be coded into the data?

Possible suggestions of features include:

- weekends vs weekdays
- business hours and time of day
- seasons
- week of year number
- month
- year
- beginning/end of month (pay days)
- quarter
- days to/from an action event(distance)
- missing or incomplete data
- etc.

All this depends on the data set and most won't apply.

some links:

http://appliedpredictivemodeling.com/blog/2015/7/28/feature-engineering-versus-feature-extraction

https://www.salford-systems.com/blog/dan-steinberg/using-dates-in-data-mining-models

http://trevorstephens.com/kaggle-titanic-tutorial/r-part-4-feature-engineering/

Comment: @Charles I am currently attempting the days from an action event. However, some of the entries don't have the action of interest, or that action is occurring for the first time. How do I represent this as a feature? Surely using a 0 implies that there are 0 days between the previous and the current action, so I can't use it in that way.

Comment: This depends on the model you're building. Some models will accept NULL values, others wont. For a regression you may need a flag - see:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299663/regression-using-continuous-variable-with-nulls

Comment: @Charles  I do collect all of these as screenshots. Just keep going.

Answer (score 14):

#### Cyclic Feature Encoding

Data that has a unique set of values that repeat in a cycle are known as cyclic data. Time-related features are mainly cyclic in nature. For example, months of a year, days of a week, hours of time, minutes of time etc... These features have a set of values and all the observations will have a value from this set only. In many ML problems, we encounter such features. Handling such features properly have proved to help in the improvement of accuracy.

**Implementation**

```
def encode(data, col, max_val):
    data[col + '_sin'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * data[col]/max_val)
    data[col + '_cos'] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * data[col]/max_val)
    return data

data['month'] = data.datetime.dt.month
data = encode(data, 'month', 12)

data['day'] = data.datetime.dt.day
data = encode(data, 'day', 31)
```

**The Logic**

A common method for encoding cyclical data is to transform the data into two dimensions using a sine and cosine transformation. Map each cyclical variable onto a circle such that the lowest value for that variable appears right next to the largest value. We compute the x- and y- components of that point using sin and cos trigonometric functions.

[image]

[image]

For handling months we consider them from 0-11 and refer to the below figure.

[image]

We can do that using the following transformations:

More on [Feature Engineering Cyclic Features](http://blog.davidkaleko.com/feature-engineering-cyclical-features.html)

Comment: This answer deserves more credit!