# Using datetime in Machine Learning

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, machine-learning, integer

I have a pandas dataset of various features, including datetime feature.
It looks like this:

```
           DD SSCL1 SEG_CLASS_CODE  FCLCLD  PASS_BK  SA  AU  DTD  DAY_OF_YEAR
0  2018-01-01     C              C       1        0   0  18   -1            1
1  2018-01-01     C              C       0        0   7  26   -1            1
2  2018-01-01     C              C       0        0   9  18   -1            1
3  2018-01-01     C              C       1       10   0  18   -1            1
4  2018-01-01     C              C       0        9   1  18   -1            1
```

I need to use `DD` column to train the model. The problem is how to encode this column?

I can`t use Cyclic Feature Encoding, described here:
[How to handle date variable in machine learning data pre-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428870/how-to-handle-date-variable-in-machine-learning-data-pre-processing)
because in the field for which I am teaching the model, 2020 is not the same as 2018, and February 2022 is not February 2023. So, years, months and days sometimes differ from each other.

My idea is to somehow transform datetime to int. For example, to get total days or hours or minutes or seconds, but i do not know the starting point (Maybe January 1st, 1970 as usual).
The easiest way to use: `dataset['DD']).apply(lambda x: x.value)`, so I`ll get something like this:

```
0          1514764800000000000
1          1514764800000000000
2          1514764800000000000
3          1514764800000000000
4          1514764800000000000
                  ...         
1450583    1577577600000000000
1450584    1577664000000000000
1450585    1577664000000000000
1450586    1577145600000000000
1450587    1577232000000000000
Name: DD, Length: 1450588, dtype: int64
```

After that I would like to use MinMaxScaler or Standardscaler.

Are there any ways to encode datetime according to my requirements?

Comment: Are you doing a classification or a regression?

Comment: @Corralien, I am doing regression, target is `PASS_BK` column

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can convert your datetime as `int` for 1970-1-1, it's a good idea to encode the time information:

```
df['DD'] = df['DD'].astype('datetime64[s]').astype(int)
```

You can also explode your `DD` column in Year, Month and Day columns like `DAY_OF_YEAR`:

```
df['YEAR'] = df['DD'].dt.year
df['MONTH'] = df['DD'].dt.month
df['DAY'] = df['DD'].dt.day
```

If your target is time-dependent (year, month, day, dayofweek, dayofyear), you should try a seasonal decomposition with different time step. After that, you can create cyclic features. Or at least, try to make some time scatter plots vs target values. Maybe you can see some relation between them.